# node update property "startsWith" of null

Tags: javascript, node.js

I just updated my node.js  on Windows 10 and I am getting this error. 
 (Cannot read property "startsWith" of null)
Now I have tried Node versions 8.10 and 9.8 and I get the same error with both. I have searched both the Node help threads and Stackoverflow and although some say the issue was fixed they do not walk me though how to fix it. Can someone help?

Comment: `I am getting this error` - when? what are you running to get this error?

Comment: `although some say the issue was fixed` - which issue? links

Comment: https://github.com/AtomLinter/linter-spell-latex/issues/17

Comment: so the issue you have is when you install `linter-spell-latex`?

Comment: I installed node. Now if I  try to install anything it throws this error message

Comment: so, you're not installing `linter-spell-latex`

Comment: see how the error message in that link has more information ... `Cannot read property 'startsWith' of null at ... lots and lots of information` - how about you share some of that with us, so we don't need to use mental telepathy :p

Comment: No. Tried to install electron and sw. Both of which I have installed and used before

Comment: what's the output of `npm -v`

Comment: Lol. That’s all it gives me. I told my computer to stop with mind games also. We are way past the first date.

Comment: really? so the error is just as you stated in the question! not helpful is it :p So, `npm -v`

Comment: Give me a minute and I’ll try to get a screen shot

Comment: no, `npm -v` what is output